# git revert -m to later merge in pull request

Tags: git, gitlab

1. I merged my feature branch into master
2. I used `git revert -m` to revert that merge
3. I created a pull request for my branch into master

But my pull request back into master doesn't show all of changes?

Answer (score 1):

Check with `git diff`. Compare your feature branch to master.  Let's say your feature branch is called "dev", you can run:

```
git diff dev master
```

And you'll see all your changes.

You can examine the history of the master branch with `git log master`, and the history of the "dev" branch with `git log dev`.